# Store entire line of text file in array line by line (not word by word; include spaces)

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program where the contents of a text file will be stored in an array line by line. I have it working, but it's only storing one word at a time.

```
  try ( Scanner fin = new Scanner ( new File("toDoItems.txt") ); ) 
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < listCount && fin.hasNext(); i++) 
          {
          textItem[i] = fin.next();
          }
    }
```

The listCount variable stores how many lines to read from the file, from the top. Instead it is telling it how many words to read. What can I do to read the entire line into the Array, without knowing how long each line may be?

I set the array size to much larger than I need and I am using the following to display the items one line at a time and only displaying the items in use (so to avoid a long list of nulls)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listCount; i++) 
          {
              String temp = textItem[i];
              System.out.println(temp);
          }
```

(For this I am restricted to arrays only. No Arraylists or lists)

Note: Most similar questions I could find are only attempting to store lines that contain a single word.

Comment: Are you bound to using a scanner? A buffered reader would get you each line at a time

Comment: Dup:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311266/read-line-with-scanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `fin.hasNext()` to `fin.hasNextLine()` and `fin.next()` to `fin.nextLine()`.

For future reference, you can find that kind of information in the [official documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: ahh! Thanks! That's what I missed!

Answer (score 1):

In ***Java8***, you can use ***stream*** with ***limit*** to ***yield*** file list content line by line:

```
 List<String> contents = Files.lines(Paths.get("toDoItems.txt")).limit(listCount).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`fin.next()` will get the next input by `token`. it should be `fin.nextLine()`